# Capacitance of parallel plate capacitor

Tags: electrostatics, capacitance, dielectric

How does metal sheet as an dielectric medium affects capacitance of parallel plate capacitor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Metal sheet touching both the condenser plates would allow the charge to pass through it. The charge would only be stored on metal plates if a dielectric medium (an insulator) is placed between them. The metal sheet is not a dielectric, it is a conductor and, allowing charges to move, there won't be charges on the metal plates and the capacitor will not be charged.

Comment: What if metal sheet in between two plates not touching the plates?